# string concatation in sql query

Tags: sql

i am having confusion with this string concatenation
could some body please brief me how this string concatenation taking place?
The confusion i am having is that, how this  `+, "", '` are working in this

```
int i = Magic.Allper("insert into tbl_notice values ('" + Label1.Text + "','" + companyTxt.Text + "','" + txtBranch.Text + "','" + dateTxt.Text + "'  ,'" + reportingTxt.Text + "','" + venueTxt.Text + "','" + eligibilityTxt.Text + "')");
```

Comment: How to ask questions - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 3):

Anything between two `"` characters is taken as a String in Java so `"','"` produces `','`. SQL requires Strings wrapped in `'`. So `"'" + venueTxt.Text + "'"` parses to `'variable value'` when the query is made.

Comment: sir why we have to use + sign in that, can't we directly use the comma sign and proceed..and if we are using the + sign and puting the string in double quotes, dont we need to put the comma too in double quotes using the +sign ?

Comment: A String literal is different from a variable, we need to grab the value of the variable (it may be a String or an int or double etc) and then join them together with the rest of the statement (using +).

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend that you don't use string concatenation in SQL queries. They provoque SQL injections. This will cause security issues.

**[What is SQL Injection?](http://www.cgisecurity.com/questions/sql.shtml)**

In response to your question, this concatenation simply takes every `TextBox.Text` property value and concatenate it into your insert statement.

I strongly recommend that you're using parameterized queries using ADO.NET lise the following example (assuming SQL Server):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        string sql = "insert into tbl_notice values(@label1, @companyTxt, @txtBranch, @dataTxt, @reportingTxt, @venueTxt, @eligibilityTxt)";

        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlParameter label1 = command.CreateParameter();
        label1.ParameterName = "@label1";
        label1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        label1.Value = Label1.Text;

        SqlParameter companyTxt = command.CreateParameter();
        companyTxt.ParameterName = "@companyTxt";
        companyTxt.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        companyTxt.Value = companyTxt.Text;

        // And so forth for each of the parameters enumerated in your sql statement.

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Close)
            connection.Open();

        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: +1 to remove downvote.  I'd also like to introduce Java programmers to "stored procedures"

Comment: @Guy: Thanks! Despite I really don't know why the downvote. Anyway! It doesn't matter! =)

Answer (score 2):

```
("insert into tbl_notice values ('" + Label1.Text + "','" + companyTxt.Text + "','" + txtBranch.Text + "','" + dateTxt.Text + "' ,'" + reportingTxt.Text + "','" + venueTxt.Text + "','" + eligibilityTxt.Text + "')");
```

Assuming that

- Label1= Hello
- companyTxt = ABC
- txtBranch = Engineering
- dateTxt = 2010-12-01
- reportingTxt = Fergusson
- venueTxt = Batcave
- eligibilityTxt = No

The above values are replaced in the SQL statement, making it look like

```
("insert into tbl_notice values ('" + Hello + "','" + ABC + "','" + Engineering + "','" + 2010-12-01 + "' ,'" + Fergusson + "','" + Batcave + "','" + No + "')");
```

The "+" operator joins the string values, resulting in

```
("insert into tbl_notice values ('Hello','ABC','Engineering','2010-12-01' ,'Fergusson','Batcave','No')")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the string.Format method for clarity

```
int i = Magic.Allper(string.Format("insert into tbl_notice values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')", 
    Label1.Text, 
    companyTxt.Text, 
    txtBranch.Text, 
    dateTxt.Text, 
    reportingTxt.Text,
    venueTxt.Text, 
    eligibilityTxt.Text));
```

You might also want to create an extension method that will make sure the strings are safe to pass to SQL in this fashion

```
public static string ToSqlFormat(this string mask, params string[] args)
{
    List<string> safe = args.ToList();
    safe.ForEach(a => a.Replace("'", "''"));
    return string.Format(mask, safe);
}
```

which will let you write

```
string insert = "insert into tbl_notice values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')";
int i = Magic.Allper(insert.ToSqlFormat( 
    Label1.Text, 
    companyTxt.Text, 
    txtBranch.Text, 
    dateTxt.Text, 
    reportingTxt.Text,
    venueTxt.Text, 
    eligibilityTxt.Text));
```